# Bootstrap resize image on table based on viewport size

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, resize, viewport

I developed a site to look up products using Bootstrap v3.3.5, see web app @ [www.montgomerycountymd.gov/dlcsearch](http://www.montgomerycountymd.gov/dlcsearch), but I need assistance on displaying the product items correctly on smaller viewport sizes such as iPhone 4/5.

I can't attach an image yet due to forum regulations, so if you could please browse to the [web app](http://www.montgomerycountymd.gov/dlcsearch) from an iPhone 4/5 and search for "Patron", you will see the product images very tiny, not sure why?

Also, on smaller viewport sizes, the logo header goes to a second row, could you please advise what is the best way to resize the logo header based on viewport size?

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you've added Bootstrap classes to the `<td>` elements to try control the widths. I noticed that in your HTML you are including the "." on the class. You don't need to do this within the HTML.

**Example:**

```
<td class=".col-xs-3">
```

should be:

```
<td class="col-xs-3">
```

If I understand your scenario correctly then my suggestion would be to add 2 classes to control the width of the columns. One class for extra small screens (mobiles) and another class for small screens (tablets) or larger.

Something like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="col-xs-5 col-sm-2"><!--your image will go here--></td>
    <td class="col-xs-4 col-sm-7"><!--your description will go here--></td>
    <td class="col-xs-3 col-sm-4 text-center"><!--your price will go here--></td>
</tr>
```

I would also use a media query to make the description text a little smaller for extra small screens.

**Example:**

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    #grdResults_ctl03_lblDescription{
        font-size:1em;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt response, it seems to work well now ;) How about resizing the logo header based on viewport size? Should I use media queries as well?

Comment: No problem @neualex. I'm glad I could help. I'm not quite sure what you mean about the logo header though. When I view the website on smaller screens the logo is displayed with the menu icon to the right of it. How does it appear when you view it? How would you like it to appear?

Comment: when I browse the web app from an iPhone 6 in portrait view, the logo image is below the menu icon :( Ideally, the logo image and menu icon should be on the same line next to each other as, apparently, you see it :)

Comment: Is it possible you are looking at a cached version of your website where the code may not have been right to display the logo and menu icon the way you wish it to? I'm also viewing your website on an iPhone 6 and it works how you describe you'd like it to work. What happens if you refresh the page?

Comment: I see why the logo was displayed on another row, I had my iPhone view as zoomed, if you try it, you will what I am referring to, see here http://postimg.org/image/mcksvx7hv/